# how to echo special characters like åäö with utf8

Tags: php, mysql, database

specialcharacters åöö in the database cant be shown when i retrieve the rows and echo it.

what can i do to have them shown propertly?

Comment: what encoding is your database/table/field using?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of character encoding options that need to be set:

- Is the database column using UTF8?
- [Is the database connection using UTF8?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)
- [Is the HTML output setting a UTF8 character set?](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset)

Comment: i dont quite understand the database connection using utf8. can someone plz explain. SET NAMES UTF-8 in the php files or in the mysql database.

Comment: Execute `SET NAMES utf8` as your first query to MySQL before executing any other queries.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your database tables, connection and output document type are UTF-8.
Good reading on the issue: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html