# SQL TEXT rows replacing æ ø å with �, HTML charset=UTF-8, MySQL row collation = utf8_general_ci

Tags: php, mysql

i have issues with SQL rows, when å ø æ is used, they are inserted as ø æ å, and it looks fine, but when i echo the row out on my page, i get a �.

If i use another collation, i get a "?" rather then a �

Comment: Duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/q/1842834/1687983..

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: the title is somewhat precise. the body of the question is not. your nickname literally says: please close this question. Imagine greater. What can we do for you?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check several things:

1. The collation of your table/database.
2. The character set of the connection (if you're using MySQL, use `mysql_set_charset`).
3. The encoding of the page.

Comment: 1. Collation is utf8_general_CI
2. no clue checking now
3. HTML charset=UTF-8

Comment: Chances are, your database connection is not set to UTF-8.

Comment: Nope character set connection  utf8

Comment: Like this? `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` If all three are done right, there is no way the characters would come out jumbled. Check and double check. And are you using a manual encoding character set override for the browser?